# MS SQL: Joining three tables and calculating average only from numeric values

Tags: sql, sql-server

i need to join two tables based on PERSON_ID, and collecting an average of each person_ID's average grade, only including the numeric values. The two tabels are called students and Grades. I need to combine the columns PERSON_ID, ENROLL_PERIOD and GRADE.
So far i have tried

```
select students.PERSON_ID, students.ENROLL_PERIOD, AVG(Cast(grades.GRADE as numeric))
from Students
INNER JOIN Grades on Students.PERSON_ID = Grades.PERSON_ID
where ENROLL_PERIOD IS NOT NULL AND ENROLL_PERIOD <> ''
Order by ENROLL_PERIOD ASC
GROUP BY PERSON_ID,ENROLL_PERIOD
```

I am getting an error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'. [156] (severity 15)

The table looks like this:

```
PERSON ID : ENROLL_PERIOD : GRADE
_________________________________
12401     :  109          :  4 
12401     :  109          :  7
12401     :  109          :  B
43245     :  112          :  12
43245     :  112          :  IB
```

I am not sure, if i am even heading in the right direction, so if anyone can help me, it would be very much appreciated. I am very new to MS SQL.

Comment: the order by must always be the last statement in the query, just move it down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the order by as last statement,
and you need to rule out all non numerical values before you can use them in the avg function.
Something like this maybe

```
declare @students table(person_id int, enroll_period int)
declare @grades table(person_id int, grade varchar(2))

insert into @students values (12401, 109), (43245, 112)
insert into @grades values(12401, '4'), (12401, '7'), (12401, 'B'), (43245, '12'), (43245, 'IB')

select s.PERSON_ID, 
       s.ENROLL_PERIOD,
       avg( case when isnumeric(g.grade) = 1 then convert(int, g.grade) else null end) as AvgGrade
from   @students s
  INNER JOIN @grades g on s.PERSON_ID = g.PERSON_ID
where  ENROLL_PERIOD IS NOT NULL AND ENROLL_PERIOD <> ''
GROUP BY s.PERSON_ID, ENROLL_PERIOD
Order by ENROLL_PERIOD ASC
```

This returns the following result

```
PERSON_ID   ENROLL_PERIOD   AvgGrade    
---------   -------------   ------- 
12401       109             5   
43245       112             12
```

**EDIT:**
on your actual tables it probably will look like this :

```
select s.PERSON_ID, 
       s.ENROLL_PERIOD,
       avg( case when isnumeric(g.grade) = 1 then convert(int, g.grade) else null end) as AvgGrade
from   students s
  INNER JOIN grades g on s.PERSON_ID = g.PERSON_ID
where  ENROLL_PERIOD IS NOT NULL AND ENROLL_PERIOD <> ''
GROUP BY s.PERSON_ID, ENROLL_PERIOD
Order by ENROLL_PERIOD ASC
```

Comment: I made a small change in my query and used NULL in stead of 0 when the value is not numerical, this produces a better result for the avg function

Comment: This works good, but my table includes 18000 PERSON_ID's. Is there anyway to automate where you rule out all numerical values?

Comment: I am not sure that I understand what you mean by `automate where you rule out all numerical values`

Comment: When you type: insert into students values (12401, 109), (43245, 112)
insert into grades values(12401, '4'), (12401, '7'), (12401, 'B'), (43245, '12'), (43245, 'IB') you manually type in each one. It would be very time consuming to do that for each row when I have 18000. I was just wondering if it would be possible to do it without typing each one in manually in the code?

Comment: no you dont need to do that. You can run the query on your actual tables. I just made some temporary tables to test my query

Comment: I edited my answer with the query that you can use without first inserting any data

Answer (score 0):

```
select students.PERSON_ID, students.ENROLL_PERIOD, AVG(Cast(grades.GRADE as numeric))
from Students
INNER JOIN Grades on Students.PERSON_ID = Grades.PERSON_ID
where ENROLL_PERIOD IS NOT NULL AND ENROLL_PERIOD <> ''

GROUP BY students.PERSON_ID,students.ENROLL_PERIOD
Order by students.ENROLL_PERIOD ASC
```

Order by should be after group by

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am getting an error Error in query (209): Ambiguous column name 'PERSON_ID'. [209] (severity 16) when executing the code. Do you know why that is?

Comment: No error message now, but it doesn't return any rows, very odd

Comment: Check your data and add in question

Answer (score 0):

You need to place of group by syntax before order by.

Quoting from https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/06/14/sql-server-easy-sequence-of-select-from-join-where-group-by-having-order-by/

The sql syntax order :

```
    SELECT yourcolumns
    FROM tablenames
    JOIN tablenames
    WHERE condition
    GROUP BY yourcolumns
    HAVING aggregatecolumn condition
    ORDER BY yourcolumns
```